# Indentifying $\sin(mx) = 2\cos(x)\sin\left[(m-1)x\right] - \sin\left[(m-2)x\right]$

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request

I encountered in a work of Joseph Fourier's the identity:

$$\sin(mx) = 2\cos(x)\sin\left[(m-1)x\right] - \sin\left[(m-2)x\right]$$
which holds for all real $m$ and $x$.

I had trouble, however, locating this in common lists of trigonometric identities.  Does this identity have a name, and where can I find it listed?  If it is not actually a common identity, how is it derived?

Comment: Most of these types of formulae come from $e^{i y}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Chebyshev_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\sin A+\sin B=2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}$$
([sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities))

Now set $A=mx,B=(m-2)x$.

Answer (score 1):

or just observe:
$$
\sin ((m-1)x \pm x) = \sin(m-1)x \cos x \pm \sin x \cos(m-1)x
$$
and add the two equations together